# Best way to handle multiple inserts

Tags: java, database, performance, jpa, playframework

Currently we are using play 1.2.5 with Java and MySQL. We have a simple JPA model (a Play entity extending Model class) we save to the database.

```
SimpleModel() test = new SimpleModel();
test.foo = "bar";
test.save();
```

At each web request we save multiple instances of the SimpleModel, for example:

```
JPAPlugin.startTx(false);
for (int i=0;i<5000;i++)
{
     SimpleModel() test = new SimpleModel();
     test.foo = "bar";
     test.save();
}
JPAPlugin.closeTx(false);
```

We are using the JPAPlugin.startTx and closeTx to manually start and end the transaction.
Everything works fine if there is only one request executing the transaction.
What we noticed is that if a second request tries to execute the loop simultaneously, the second request gets a "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [SimpleModel]" since the first request locks the table but is not done until the second request times out.
This results in multiple:

> ERROR AssertionFailure:45 - an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session)
>   org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in SimpleModel entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Another disinfect is that the CPU usage during the inserts goes crazy.

To fix this, I'm thinking to create a transaction aware queue to insert the entities sequentially but this will result in huge inserting times.
What is the correct way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

JPAPlugin on Play Framwork 1.2.5 is not thread-safe and you will not resolve this using this version of Play.

That problem is fixed on Play 2.x, but if you can't migrate try to use hibernate directly.

Comment: I'll try with 2x and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to handle transactions yourself in this scenario.

Instead either put your inserts in a controller method or in an asynchronous job if the task is time consuming.

Jobs and controller both handle transasctions.

However check that this is really what you are trying to achieve. Each http request creating 5000 records does not seem realistic. Perhaps it would make more sense to have a container model with a collection?

Comment: Each request starts a Play job, but the problem remains.

Comment: Try get rid of the startTx and stopTx since transactions are handled by the JobPlugin. Are you are running your jobs asynchronously using using job.now() form the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a transaction for the entire insert?   Does it matter if the database is not locked during the data import?

You can simply create a job and execute it for each insert:

```
for (int i=0;i<5000;i++)
{
     new Job() { 
       doJob(){ 
          SimpleModel() test = new SimpleModel();
          test.foo = "bar";
          test.save();
      }.now();
}
```

This will create a single transaction for each insert and get rid of your database lock issue.